# nest js | I have many collections and all of them start by full-year how to make a dynamic model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I have many collections and all of them start by full-year how to make a dynamic model  do take that full year from param and got to the collection started by the same full year
after the client calls the endpoint, he will send the full year like 2020 in param   I will  take the and navget to the collecton start by 2020-foo for expalem   I do this logic by Express how to do that logic by nest js

i read this part in the nest's docs but don't reach to anything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you injecting model in class you can use variables

like this:

```
@InjectModel(`full-year${yearVariable}`)
private readonly fullYearModel: Model<FullYearDocument>
```